# pyenv tcshell eval pyenv int response illegal variable name

Tags: python, linux, shell

I can't figure out how to setup pyenv correctly to switch python versions.

Actually I have to switch/try newer python versions on SUSE LINUX ENTERPRISE SERVER 10 SP3 (I know it's an old linux but sadly we have to maintain some software for this platform). I found pyenv and tried to set it up using the a tcshell. My .tcshrc file looks like this:

```
setenv PYENV_ROOT $HOME/.pyenv
set path = ($path $PYENV_ROOT/bin)
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

I had to adopt the variable setup to fit tcshell commands. The *pyenv* command is found and seems to kind of work. Which means I could install python versions, and "switch" them but *python -V* always gives me the old system version which is Python 2.4.2.

So the first issue is, that I can't switch the globally used python version.

Nevertheless i think there is still an initialization error because the eval command returns

```
Illegal variable name.
```

after reloading the shell with *exec $SHELL*. The failing *pyenv init* may be the root of the problem!?

What can i do to properly setup pyenv using tcshell?

**How to correct the eval line in my .tcshrc?**

P.S. Maybe i misunderstood something basic pyenv related, if so, please let me know, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `pyenv init -` was not working in *tcshell* (had missing command calls) ...

So the solution is switching to bash and everything works!

Maybe it's more a workaround than a solution but nevertheless i prefer bash over tcshell.